# Is there an irrational number containing only $0$'s and $1$'s with continued fraction entries less than $10$?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, continued-fractions

The number $$0.10111001001000000000001$$ has continued fraction $$[0, 9, 1, 8, 9, 5, 1, 1, 5, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 6, 1, 1, 8, 2, 5, 8, 1, 9, 9, 5, 2
, 8, 1, 1, 6, 4, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 5, 1, 1, 5, 9, 8, 1, 9]$$

So, the maximum values is $9$. But we are only at $23$ digits. Can we produce larger decimal expansions with the required property ? Perhaps arbitary large ones ?

> Is there an irrational number, such that the decimal expansion contains only ones and zeros and the continued fraction contains no entry larger than $9$ ?

Comment: (+1) An interesting question on the intersection of Cantor-like sets.

Comment: $$0.1011010000001000000010000000000000$$ $$0000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000001$$ is far better with $87$ digits! Seems that we can continute forever, if we add a digit $1$ and then insert enough $0$'s between the last two ones ...

Comment: But I would prefer sequences without such long $0$-sequences, if possible :)

Comment: A shorter example without long sequences is $$0.1011010011100100111101101110101$$